# Convert CreationTimeStamp type to string

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am getting time from `pod.CreationTimeStamp` and trying to store it in a variable.how can i store time in to string.

```golang
 tmp := json_format{}
 pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(v1.ListOptions{LabelSelector:app_name})

 for _, pod := range pods.Items {
     tmp.Creation_Time = append(tmp.Creation_Time,pod.CreationTimestamp) 
}
```

Its giving this error: `cannot convert pod.ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp (type "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".Time) to type string`

```
type json_format struct{
Creation_Time string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `CreationTimestamp` to string you can use the method `String()`.

Example:

```golang
timeInString := pod.CreationTimestamp.String()
```

Your code:

```golang
tmp := json_format{}
 pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(v1.ListOptions{LabelSelector:app_name})

 for _, pod := range pods.Items {
     tmp.Creation_Time = append(tmp.Creation_Time,pod.CreationTimestamp.String()) 
}
```

Another correction request:

The `Creatio_Time` field should be slice (i.e. []string) instead of single string.

```
type json_format struct{
Creation_Time []string
}
```